# I am out of shape. I need a routine to be able to do push ups, curl ups, run the mile, touch my toes, and lift weight in 2 months

Tags: exercise, push-ups, flexibility, routine, curls

**Background:**

I am 13 and would like to improve my overall fitness levels (see goals below). I do not have ANY exercise equipment except a pull up bar. I also have a steep hill for running.

**My daily diet is:**

burrito, cereal, meat, salad, bread, a small candy, and fruit if I have some.

**Goals:**

- Sum 10:00 mile run
- Complete 50+ consecutive push-ups.
- Complete 50+ consecutive sit-ups
- Complete 20+ chin-ups
- Able to touch toes
- Able to lift a decent [sic] amount of weight. **????**

**Restrictions:**

- Max 1 hour per day available for exercise.
- Achieve goals in 2 months.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What sort of shape are you looking for? Better flexibility? More strength? Better endurance? Toned muscles? Do you have constraints on the sort of equipment? Diet? Do you have a place you can train?

Comment: I would like to be able to run the mile in less than ten minutes. I don't have any equipment besides a pull-up bar. I do have space to train, though. I have a steep hill in the back yard if that helps.And I could probably be better about diet. An example day of eating would be: A bowl of cereal, a burrito, a bowl of strawberries, lasagna, salad, and a roll. Then a fun size candy at night.

Comment: And I don't want to buy exercise equipment.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/what-are-the-best-ways-for-a-beginner-to-ease-into-running then. It's got good advice for starting runners. I revised your question to include information from your comments.

Comment: @Indigo2003 - I second that. I'm going to have to close this as being way too broad, but I don't want you to take that as discouragement in any way. We all want you to get in better shape and enjoy it, so if you can edit your question and narrow it down, we can give you a lot of advice or point you to resources that can help.

Comment: @Indigo2003 - Here is another q/a that may give you some helpful info on how to get started http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/12860/beginner-in-physical-fitness-need-tips-and-advices/12864#12864.  A proper diet is also crucial to developing a healthy body.

Comment: I'm editing it right now. Any third tag ideas?