# How to choose "Neutral shoes" for long distance endurance running?

Tags: running-shoes, endurance, long-distance-running

This answer [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/166/2598) mention that `"neutral shoes"` are better for long distance running. I have used Adidas Supernova for a very long time with inversion support (ofc changed them every year or so, tried other but always gone back to them -- the name may have changed but they have the inversion -support thing and wide thing in the front of the shoes, basically the reason I like them). Now I have tried longer distance running lasting hours and I feel that the Supernovas are not good for them, they make my outer part of the foot hurting -- to the unacceptable level of pain. So I am now looking for some `neutral shoes`. It is surely harder to test `"neutral shoes"` for long distance running because one should buy them all to trial with them! Some generic hints or instructions? I run on tarmac.

`"neutral shoes"`? Perhaps, this is an area of research, interesting what people will come up with `"neutral shoes"`. Are they `no-inversion-supported shoes`, `vibram-style barefoot shoes`, `Nike Free shoes` or something else? At least, this trend is now even in cheaper shops like [here](http://www.dealextreme.com/p/unique-stylish-outdoor-shoes-black-size-42-pair-52941?r=36798618), will update when I know more about the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Running long distance doesn't mean you have to automatically go with neutral (pronation) shoes.

First, find out what kind of pronation you have and by how much THEN select your shoe type.

Here's a [link](http://www.therunningadvisor.com/running_shoes.html) to a guide to choosing your running shoe.

Answer (score 1):

By neutral they mean subtalar neutral.  This is the position of the subtalar joint in which the foot is neither pronated nor supinated. When the hindfoot is neutral.

***Excessive or prolonged motion or lack of motion will cause various deformities and pathologies. Proper biomechanics allow human beings to walk, run, jump, and move freely without pain or dysfunction.***

A pair of shoes off the shelf cannot be "neutral" as the topography of everyones foot differs. In addition the density (hardness) of your shoe insert will vary based on your unique requirements.

To attain this neutral position you must be assessed by a Podiatrist and have a custom orthotic (shoe insert) casted and created.

> Foot biomechanics studies the relationship of the foot to the lower
> leg. During walking and running the musculoskeletal system generates
> forces to propel the body forward.
>
> The foot serves two main functions.
>
> - It acts as a mobile adaptor to adjust to varying terrain
> - rigid lever for forward propulsion in locomotion.
>
> The two functions are time specific in that when the foot spends too much time being a
> mobile adaptor it is not spending enough time being a rigid lever and
> vice versa.
>
> Biomechanics of the foot analyzes how the various
> structures of the foot, work together to perform specific functions
> (timing being of utmost importance.)

http://www.wefixfeet.ca/sites/default/files/biomechanics.pdf